# Laravel 5.3.14 - Disable auto login after registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to `laravel`. I am building a project using this amazing framework but I am not facing a problem. I would like to prevent the framework from logging the user after registration but I am unable. I searched on google and what I am getting is for the version 5.2 which is different from mine.

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: after registration just do: $request->session()->flush();

Comment: I have to display a flash message and this method is going to prevent it

Comment: so put flash message to variable and pass to view and flush the session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

You can do this by overriding the `register()` method in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`.

In `RegisterController.php`, create a new method to override the parent method.

```
// In your RegisterController.php

public function register(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    // validate the form 

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    
    // add the user
    $this->create($request->all());

    // redirect user
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

---

Here's what the parent method looks like. Notice the line `$this-guard()->login()`

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    // notice this line:
    $this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Notice it logs in the user after registering it. We basically overrode this method and kept everything the same except we didn't log the user in.

Comment: Thanks, before seeing your answer, I commented the line `$this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all()));` and everything was ok. but I think your answer is better.

Comment: Hey @Taylor, check this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864069/set-a-string-field-to-null-in-laravel-5-3-14

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.4 the RegisterController.php is found in this path

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth

you can comment this

**

> `$this->guard()->login($user);`

**